# App crash when user changes fragment using NavigationDrawer during volley async operations

Tags: android, android-fragments, asynchronous, android-volley

I created an application based on Android Studio's Navigation Drawer template.

I have 3 fragment, each one implements various Vollye async Network request.

The problem is:
when a user, playing on fragment A, fires an action that send a volley async network request and, prior to get the result and UI updates, it switches to fragment B, the application raise a NULL pointer exception, obviously.

Basically, the callback of the fragment A's async network request can't update the UI because fragment A was replaced by fragment B with completely different UI elements, the Fragment A context was destroyed.

So, i suppose the problem is the logic of the fragment swapping/switching.

Here is my MainActivity "**onNavigationDrawerItemSelected**" method, called every time a user tap on NavigationDrawer element:

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position)
{
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment frag = null;

    switch (position)
    {
        case 0: // A
            frag = FragmentA.newInstance(position + 1);
            break;
        case 1: // B
            frag = FragmentB.newInstance(position + 1);
            break;
        case 2: // C
            frag = FragmentC.newInstance(position + 1);
            break;
        default:
    }

    if (frag != null)
    {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, frag)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

And now the problem is clear, every time a user tap on a NavigationDrawer's element the selected fragment is inflate into the layout, replacing (destroying) the old one.

What is the best way to solve this problem?

A user may be able to switch between fragment in every moment, i do not want to disable UI waiting to the conclusion of a specific async network request, and imho clearing Volley queue to stop async request being fired during onPause()/onDestroy() method is not a good solution.. it's not the solution.

If user tap on fragment B i want to:

- check if there are Volley queued request of fragment A -> clear them.
- if any request was fired and system is waiting for response, get the 
  response (when it comes) and process it with or without updating the UI.

The problem is the fragment swapping logic, i guess. How do i have to manage fragment swapping/switching?

**UPDATE**

Example of error on getting sharedPreferences object:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: ***************, PID: 21174
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
```

Code that cause the NULLpE. The callback (defined and executed inside the FragmentA) of the FragmentA's Volley Async Request, called when the response comes (after the user may switch to Fragment B) do the following:

```
[...]
// we are inside FragmentA
// Volley Async Network Request callback code
APILibrary lib = new APILibrary(getActivity());
[...]
```

This is the APILibrary constructor method:

```
public APILibrary(Context context) {
  this.fooObject = new FooObject(context)
}
```

This is the FooObject constructor method where the FATAL EXCEPTION occurs:

```
public FooObject(Context context) {
    mContext =  context;
    mSharedPrefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences(MYFOOTAG, mContext.MODE_PRIVATE);
}
```

**Another example of Fatal Error**

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.foo.bar, PID: 20676
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
        at android.view.ViewConfiguration.get(ViewConfiguration.java:359)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3580)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3675)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:491)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:200)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:196)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:192)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:188)
        at android.widget.TableRow.<init>(TableRow.java:61)
        at com.foo.bar.FragmentA.initTable(FragmentA.java:879)
        at com.foo.bar.FragmentA.parseData(FragmentA.java:681)
        at com.foo.bar.FragmentA$7.update(FragmentA.java:436)
        at com.foo.bar.CustomAPI$1.onResponse(CustomAPI.java:283)
        at com.foo.bar.CustomAPI$1.onResponse(CustomAPI.java:280)
        at com.foo.bar.CustomRequest.deliverResponse(CustomRequest.java:83)
        at com.foo.bar.CustomRequest.deliverResponse(CustomRequest.java:22)
        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

The code that generates the Null Pointer Exception, after the user switch to another Fragment while an async task is running on FragmentA, is:

```
at com.foo.bar.FragmentA.initTable(FragmentA.java:879):
TableRow headrow = new TableRow(getActivity());
```

Comment: Please post the part of your code that shows how and where you called `getSharedPreferences`.

Comment: Done! i posted the code that raise the FATAL EXCEPTION

Comment: Where did you declare/initialize `MYFOOTAG`?

Comment: please assume that the code generate no compile errors. MYFOOTAG is declared into FooObject class as a static final String.. As the error trace explain there is a method call on a null reference:  mContext.getSharedPreferences() -> mContext is null because user switch to another fragment before this code is called

Comment: I think it should be `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` not `mContext.MODE_PRIVATE`.

Comment: it isn't a problem here. i added new fatal error example.